# Gunicorn, no module named 'myproject

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm installing a previously built website on a new server. I'm not the original developer.

I've used Gunicorn + nginx in the past to keep the app alive (basically following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04)), but am having problems with it here.

I `source venv/bin/activate`, then `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` works well and everything is running as expected. I shut it down and run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`, and get the following:

```
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15259] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15259] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (15259)
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15259] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15262] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15262
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15262] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15262] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15262)
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15259] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-09-13 01:11:47 +0000] [15259] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I believe it has something to do with the structure of the whole application. Before, I've built apps with the basic structure of:

```
myproject
├── manage.py
├── myproject
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── component1
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── component2
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   └── ...
```

This one, instead, has a structure like:

```
myproject
├── apps
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │     └── ...
│   ├── catalogue
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │     └── ...
│   ├── checkout
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │     └── ...
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │     └── ...
│   ├── customer
│   ├── dashboard
│   └──  __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── project_static
│   ├── assets
│   ├── bower_components
│   └── js
├── public
│   ├── emails
│   ├── media
│   └── static
├── settings
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── dev.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── local.py
│   └── production.py
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── basket
│   ├── blog
│   └── ....
├── urls.py
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   └── share
└── wsgi.py
```

So, there's no 'main' module running the show, which is what I expect gunicorn is looking for.

Any thoughts?

**wsgi.py**:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Where is `myproject.wsgi`? What are its contents?

Comment: @Plasma i just updated the question to include the contents of `wsgi.py` -- from what I understand this is what gunicorn is looking for, am I mistaken?

Comment: If you run gunicorn by doing `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`, then gunicorn will look for the file `myproject.wsgi` and use the variable called `application` in that file.

Comment: I just tried this with a bare django install, the difference being that `venv` is one directory above the app. So we have: `[...]/myproject/venv` and `[...]/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py` --- this works. (there's no `myproject.wsgi`)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Your error message is

```
ImportError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'
```

You ran the app with

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

And wsgi.py has the line

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
```

This is the disconnect.  In order to recognize the project as `myproject.wsgi` the *parent* directory would have to be on the python path... running

```
cd .. && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

Would eliminate that error.  However, you would then get a different error because the wsgi.py file refers to `settings` instead of `myproject.settings`.  This implies that the app was intended to be run from the root directory instead of one directory up.  You can figure this out for sure by looking at the code- if it uses absolute imports, do they usually say `from myproject.app import ...` or `from app import ...`.  If that guess is correct, your correct commmand is

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:application
```

If the app does use `myproject` in all of the paths, you'll have to modify your PYTHONPATH to run it properly...

```
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this line worked for me : 
`PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`

Comment: My hangup was that the naming convention is that of python and not the directory structure. ex: `myproject.wsgi` corresponds to `myproject/wsgi.py` and not the file `myproject.wsgi` where `wsgi` is the extension. Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: Does `myproject` in `myproject.wsgi` stands for the folder name? or the Django project name? In my case, the folder name is different, and I can't use both names

Comment: That is a `fully qualified module name`. In the usual case, the first name in this path will be the top directory that contains a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: (it would be the same path you would use with `from myproject.wsgi import application`)

Comment: Can you help me explain what to do you mean by PYTHONPATH=pwd/.. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application ? I've added the PYTHONPATH="home/user/pyapps/myproject/" to the venv/bin/activate and then run gunicorn bin as: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application . in my venv the sockets runs smoothly until i restart it. Help here boys really appreciated! =) @AsherMancinelli

Comment: if wsgi.py is in the myproject folder AND there is a `__init__.py` file in that folder, in order for `myproject.wsgi:application` to be the correct path, your PYTHONPATH variable would need to contain `/home/user/pyapps`. It works because the first module you specified in your gunicorn command 'myproject' is found in the folder specified by PYTHONPATH.

Comment: The way you have it set, `myproject` is on the search path. So when you do `myproject.wsgi` is looks inside `myproject` for a folder called `myproject` (and doesn't find it).

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` environment variable works for me, alternatively, pass it that in with the `--pythonpath` parameter, which also works.  https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#pythonpath

Comment: Hi @PaulBecotte I have a very similar problem can you help me please???  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886575/gunicorn-start-failing-no-module-found

Comment: I have a similar issue and i've been stucked for days. Any help will be appreciated please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465541/django-vuejs-app-deployed-to-heroku-showing-application-error-on-page?noredirect=1#comment112420587_63465541

Comment: For those of you who have come here that are not using the command line to start gunicorn, use the variable name `chdir` followed by `= "/my/path/"` to change to your django project directory in your config file.

Answer (score 6):

For my side,
My project structure is

```
myproject
├── manage.py
├── myproject
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   ├── ..
Dockerfile
docker-composer.yml
```

So in docker-composer.yml, when command

> gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

i get following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'

What we have to do is, we must run gunicorn command inside  folder, not project root. This is the working code

```
sh -c "cd ./myproject && gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Before gunicorn command, we have to change directory with "cd ./project". Inside the "myproject" directory,  gunicorn can recognise our projects clearly.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Changing directories using the shell instead of using gunicorn's `--chdir` option.

Comment: For me I was deploying on digitalocean, and this is the correct answer, and i didn't need to bind the port `cd ./myproject && gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application`

Answer (score 3):

Run these command after replacing your python working directory path.

```
# Go to your current working directory
cd /path/to/folder

# Activate your virtual environment. Ignore if already in activated mode
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate

# Install gunicorn in virtualenv
pip3 install gunicorn

# Run this command. Replace PORT and app name accordingly
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `supervisor` then you have to set `environment` in supervisor config file as bellow.

`environment=HOME="/home/to/your/project/root"`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. The gunicorn was being run by a globally installed package, not the one that was installed in the virtual environment. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868695/12042940) answer helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. I recreated the virtual environment and install gunicorn using pip3 (not using apt) and it worked fine