# Setting PYTHONPATH in Ubuntu 16.04 for a Docker image to run properly

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, gunicorn

I have a docker image that is running a gunicorn process, but everytime it runs I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'crm'`.  So I am following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461113/5779280) to solve this issue.

However, when I run

```
ENTRYPOINT ["PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/..", "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "web_interface:app", "-w 4", "-t 90", "--log-level=debug", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000",  "--reload"]
```

the container spits back a

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. \": stat PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. : no such file or directory"
```

Any idea how I can run the PYTHONPATH command?

I should state that it works locally on my Mac, but not in the Ubuntu container.

What I have tried:

`"PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.."`

`"PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)/.."`

`"PYTHONPATH=$PWD/.."`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should define the environment outside of the `ENTRYPOINT` with the [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH /absolute/path/to/the/pythonpath/inside/the/container
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "web_interface:app", "-w 4", "-t 90", "--log-level=debug", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000",  "--reload"]
```

Comment: Great, I like this answer better. So I could just use `$PWD/..` instead of the path name

Comment: Not sure about the `$PWD` as it depends on the current `WORKDIR` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir). You're building an image so you have control on the paths, no need to be relative from your application dir.

Comment: I used `ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}"` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be working

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--pythonpath=`$PWD`/..", "web_interface:app", "-w 4", "-t 90", "--log-level=debug", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000",  "--reload"]
```