# Gunicorn does not work when try to launch Django application

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am following [this](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application) tutorial, until up to this part.

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn helloworld.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3
```

My directories is like this.

```
awesome_app
-awesome_app
--__init__.py
--celery.py
--settings.py
--urls.py
--wsgi.py
-awesome_app_to_do_list
--a lot of stuffs here
-manage.py
-start.sh
```

Here is the content of my wsgi.py.

```
"""
WSGI config for airport project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "awesome_app.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I adapted the launch code to this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo starting gunicorn
exec gunicorn awesome_app.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 \
    --workers 3
```

After I make it executable and run the script from the root of the project awesome_app and not from awesome_app/awesome_app. I received this error, `ImportError: No module named 'myproject'`. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460892/gunicorn-no-module-named-myproject) SO discussion, but the error is still there. What should I do?

Comment: Where do you import `myproject`?

Comment: There is a mismatch between `airport` in the wsgi file, `awesome_app` in the launch script and `myproject` in the error message.

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule, I don't know. It is says everywhere in Python + Gunicorn tutorial.

Comment: @Alasdair, it is supposed to be `awesome_app` sorry typo from wrong project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue. Apparently the culprit was celery.py settings. In it, I has these codes.

```
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myproject')
```

Stupidly enough, I just copy paste codes from Celery + Django example. Even more stupid because my web application works fine, idk why.

So I change that codes in celery.py to these and it is working.

```
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'awesome_app.settings')

app = Celery('awesome_app')
```

For anyone comes in having the same problem please take a look at `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')` and change `myproject` to whatever your Django project named.

Answer (score 1):

Get into your project directory and try just running this in your command line instead of running the script and see if it works:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myprojectname.wsgi
```

Comment: I ran `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 awesome_app.wsgi` from the project root. Same error: `ImportError: No module named 'myproject'`.

Answer (score 0):

BaconSandwich's answer is the way to go. However, If the script is required, try setting the working directory to the directory the script is located in.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Try prepending this to the script and see if it works.

Comment: Hey Dorian, it still have the same error, `ImportError: No module named 'myproject'`. Nevertheless, it is good to know to change directory where the script is located. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `The ONBUILD image variants are deprecated, and their usage is discouraged. For more details, see docker-library/official-images#2076.` check: [Python Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)

So for a best practice way with more understanding to what's actually happening the dockerfile will be like this:

**IMPORTANT** Make sure you are in your host directory that has your initiated django project and the excuted `start.sh`.

1) Fetching `FROM` a base image `FROM python:2` change it to 3 if you want to use python3.

2) Specify `WORKDIR` inside the docker img lets say `WORKDIR /usr/scr/project` 
that will insure a correct path to gunicorn when running the `start.sh`

3) Copying `COPY` requirements.txt to the docker image `COPY requirements.txt ./`

4) Runing `RUN` pip to install your requirements inside the docker image `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

5) Copying `COPY` all the project files into the docker image `COPY . .`

4) Define a starter command `CMD` `CMD ./start.sh`.

**DockerFile**

```
# Dockerfile

# Fetching `FROM` a base image `FROM python:2` 
# Change it to 3 if you want to use python3.
FROM python:2

# Specify WORKDIR inside the docker img 
# Lets say WORKDIR /usr/scr/project 
# That will insure a correct path to gunicorn when running the start.sh
WORKDIR /usr/scr/project

# Copying COPY requirements.txt to the docker image COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY requirements.txt ./

#Runing RUN pip to install your requirements inside the docker image pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copying COPY all the project files into the docker image COPY . .
COPY . .

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# Define a starter command CMD CMD ./start.sh.
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

**edited**: for missing RUN in the dockerfile