# Internal Server Error 500 when deploying Django Application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed meticulously the official AWS guide to deploy a Django App to Elastic Beanstalk (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) for a school project. It is working locally, but when I try to deploy it shows a 500 Error message. I went through many adjustments in my code but they don't seem effective. The AWS dashboard shows one warning that says: Environment health has transitioned from OK to Warning. 100% of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. Could it be a timezone problem as I am currently in Europe?

I tried to change debug mode from true to false, but I don't think that's the problem. the I truly do not understand why it's not working, I never got an error in the execution in the terminal and it always deployed everything correctly. It is just not showing the web page for some reason.

```
MacBook-Air-di-Davide:ebdjango davidemerlin$ eb create django-env
Creating application version archive "app-190718_165248".
Uploading ebdjango/app-190718_165248.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: django-env
  Application name: ebdjango
  Region: eu-central-1
  Deployed Version: app-190718_165248
  Environment ID: e-3mxbcch2rm
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.6
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2019-07-18 14:52:51.893000+00:00
Printing Status:
2019-07-18 14:52:51    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2019-07-18 14:52:52    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-725098113628 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2019-07-18 14:53:16    INFO    Created security group named: sg-0d5da9ecf4206ab11
2019-07-18 14:53:32    INFO    Created load balancer named: awseb-e-3-AWSEBLoa-GCK3W368WNAW
2019-07-18 14:53:32    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-3mxbcch2rm-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-10HEII5KA2YFV
2019-07-18 14:53:32    INFO    Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-3mxbcch2rm-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-16YCNNVJS4QJG
 -- Events -- (safe to Ctrl+C)

eb status
```

```
Environment details for: django-env
  Application name: ebdjango
  Region: eu-central-1
  Deployed Version: None
  Environment ID: e-3mxbcch2rm
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.6
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: django-env.q7fdcfwnii.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2019-07-18 14:53:32.535000+00:00
  Status: Launching
  Health: Grey
Alert: An update to the EB CLI is available. Run "pip install --upgrade awsebcli" to get the latest version.
(base) MacBook-Air-di-Davide:ebdjango davidemerlin$ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-190718_165726".
Uploading ebdjango/app-190718_165726.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2019-07-18 14:57:28    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2019-07-18 14:57:31    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-07-18 14:57:53    INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
2019-07-18 14:57:53    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.

Alert: An update to the EB CLI is available. Run "pip install --upgrade awsebcli" to get the latest version.
(base) MacBook-Air-di-Davide:ebdjango davidemerlin$ eb open'''

I expect to load the page at django-env.q7fdcfwnii.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Comment: what do the logs (`eb logs`) and health (`eb health`) look like? Can you ssh into your instance?

Comment: As @danimal points out, check `eb logs`. Considering HTTP 500s are being returned, you should see stack traces in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to deploy my Django Rest Api to Beanstalk by following [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html). And I encountered the same **Status Code 500** error.

I managed to solve this problem by making below **two** changes:

1. AWS Beanstalk's python 3.6 environment doesn't seem to work well with **latest Django** versions. So I created a new **python 3.7** environment using this command.

   ```
   eb init -p python-3.7 django-tutorial
   ```
2. Changed **WSGI Path to**:

   > WSGIPath: YourDjangoProjectFolder.wsgi:application

All other things are same as described in that documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you resolve it? I struggled for weeks but with a 502 after following exactly the instructions.

Then I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460892/gunicorn-no-module-named-myproject) and deduced it was a typo or outdated instructions (`*/wsgi.py` should be `*.wsgi:application`).

Created a [pull request](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-elastic-beanstalk-developer-guide/pull/86) to AWS docs and they've updated since.

Comment: "*/wsgi.py should be *.wsgi:application" is the answer I'm suggesting and I provided supporting links to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, until I realized I hadn't included the following line in my settings.py file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['eb-django-app-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

Replacing the link inside the brackets with my own custom application link, as stated in step 5 of the tutorial.

After saving the file and committing, I was able to get rid of the 500 error.