# Cannot start Gunicorn, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

Here's my folder structure:

```
~/myprojectdir
    manage.py
    myprojectenv/
        bin/
            activate
            gunicorn
            pip3
            python3
            ...
        lib/
            python3.6
            ...
    fishercoder/
        fishercoder/
            asgi.py
            urls.py
            settings.py
            wsgi.py
            __init__.py
            ...
        blog/
            views.py
            urls.py
            models.py
            admin.py
            apps.py
            templates/
            ...
        catalog/
            views.py
            urls.py
            models.py
            admin.py
            apps.py
            templates/
            ...
```

I have run `source myprojectenv/bin/activate`

Here's my `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've replaced this line:

`myproject.wsgi:application`

with this

`fishercoder.wsgi:application` or this

`wsgi:application`

following the suggestion from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460892/gunicorn-no-module-named-myproject)

Restarted Gunicorn.
No luck in either.

My `~/myprojectdir/fishercoder/wsgi.py` looks like this:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fishercoder.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any one could shed any light on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to your tree structure, your `wsgi.py` file is in `~/myprojectdir/fishercoder/fishercoder/wsgi.py`.

Comment: I copied this `wsgi.py` from there to `~/myprojectdir/fishercoder` also. I have it in both places now. What needs to be done?

Comment: I don't see any `__init__.py` file. directories without it are not python packages.

Comment: just added it in the question. thanks

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` file? Which directory is your root package? How your `setup.py` file is done?

Comment: No, I really don't have a `setup.py` file, I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04, any instructions for `setup.py` would be great!

Comment: ok, I found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Comment: Yes, you need a `setup.py` file. So that your project and it’s dependencies are installed in your virtualenv. When you deploy, it’s a requirement. It’s also a best practice in development mode. So, follow a good tutorial and it will work. Mind your tree structure too.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking at https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs now, what's a proper tree structure for production Django project?

Comment: No, this is the DJango documentation project.

Comment: Hmm, I've gone through this https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs and even in this official tutorial, it didn't mention `setup.py` in a Django project, any ideas how to study this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your are in development mode, you can link your virtualenv with your source code so that gunicorn can found it.

To do that, activate your virtualenv and install your project in edit mode:

```sh
source /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/activate
cd /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir/fishercoder
pip install -e .
```

Of course you need a `setup.py` in your project directory.

Your wsgi file can be at any level but it is usually in your root package.

But, currently, your root package seems to be `fishercoder`, so in your configuration file, you need to write: `fishercoder.wsgi:application`.

Comment: I'm not in dev mode, configuring this on an EC2 instance, and I was running in virtualenv. I did try `fishercoder.wsgi:application` no luck.

Comment: could you educate me on this: `pip install -e .` what does this do? I didn't figure it out. thanks

Comment: You should try to run your application in development mode before deploying…

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone is also bumped into the same issue, I was able to unblock myself by copying the contents from `~/myprojectdir/fishercoder/` directory up to its parent directory `~/myprojectdir/`.

And then change this line in my `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file

```
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application
```

to be

```
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          fishercoder.wsgi:application
```

Apparently this is hacky and not ideal, but at least it works now.
I'm still trying to find a tutorial to help me set up setup.py in a more python way.